# Why does Vertex AI endpoints give results from one deployed model?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

I have successfully created two models (that take in a float, perform a simple computation and return another float) on Vertex AI Models and created an endpoint for both of them, separately.

However, when calling a prediction from the UI (via Vertex AI Models), I always get the result from one of them. The "deployedModelId" in the Response body differs from both endpoints, but does not align with the model IDs of the two models.

The same goes for deploying both models on 1 endpoint with traffic-split 50/50%. I get 50% of the times one deployedModelId and 50% of the times another. However, the predictions output is always the result from one of the model and the deployedModelIds don't align with the two model IDs.

It seems like only one model is used when the predictions are returned from an endpoint.

I have checked that the models are not accidentally the same so I downloaded the models from Vertex AI Models and called a prediction when loading in the models locally. I get the right response then.

I have tested calling predictions both on the UI and the python SDK, both methods give me the same, wrong, predictions for one of the models.

Comment: Have you set up your web app to to get the predictions from your trained model ? Such as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tutorials/image-recognition-custom/serving#3_use_a_web_app_to_send_prediction_requests). As explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tutorials/image-recognition-custom/serving#2_deploy_a), you should create a Cloud Function to make requests to the particular end point you created, sending requests to the Vertex AI API's REST interface. Have you configured you Cloud Functions with different endpoints?

Comment: Hello @AlexandreMoraes, thank you for your response. I have not tried this setup, but even if this would yield the proper results, I do not believe that Cloud Functions should be the only way to call Vertex AI's APIs. I believe there is a bug in the backend.

Comment: It is advisable to follow the documentation's instructions on how to call Vertex AI, as it is from Google. Could you try this set up I shared previously and let me know if it worked?

Comment: I just want to know: What is the expectation for multiple models in the same endpoint? Is it supposed to use random model for each request? Why would the user want that? Thank you.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I've created a clip that should explain the issue. I'm convinced there is a bug in Vertex AI endpoints. More information can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zs8z1nA1uhUhNIzHTUxWJ1h6okQ8vslK/view?usp=sharing